# FileMaker cURL Problems

Tags: php, curl, post, filemaker

so I've looked around everywhere to try and figure out the problem to this, but I haven't really been able to piece it together. With the recent FM 16 arrival we have gained cURL functionality, which before I was just using a simple PHP script to do all of the processing and the importing to FileMaker using the API.

I'm trying to convert this:

```
$url = 'https://' . $organization . '.qualtrics.com/API/v3/responseexports';
$header = array(
    'X-API-TOKEN: ' . $apiToken,
    'Content-Type: application/json'
);
$postData = array(
    'surveyId' => $surveyId,
    'format' => 'csv',
    'useLabels' => true
);

$d = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($d, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => $url,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $header,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode($postData)
));

$response = curl_exec($d);
```

And my cURL options in FileMaker looks like this:

> "--request POST" &
>   "--data surveyId=$surveyID & format=csv & useLabels=true" &
>   "--header \"X-API-TOKEN: $apiKey\"" &
>   "--header \"Content-Type: application/json\""

But all I get is a response from that server that says it doesn't understand my call.

Comment: You should not need to include "--request POST" as specifying --data will send as POST anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Posting a quick reply away from my machine, but you need to split up your strings and variables. Like this : ...surveyId=" & $surveyID & "format=...

I haven't looked at the rest of the syntax yet.

EDIT:

To see what the final call that gets passed is, you should prepare everything and store it in a variable which you then pass as cURL options. If you have FileMaker Pro Advanced you can use the Data Viewer to check the variable for errors. If not, you can put a global variable on a layout as a merge variable to see it's content after you run a script.

A script step to set the variable should be something like this:

Set Variable $myHeader (or $$myHeader if you want to examine it outside the script)

```
Let ([
$surveyID = "MySurveyID";
$apiKey = "MyApiKey"];
  "--request POST --data surveyId=" & $surveyID & "&format=csv&useLabels=true --header \"X-API-TOKEN: " & $apiKey & "\" --header \"Content-Type: application/json\""
)
```

(You may have defined the $surveyID and $apiKey variables elsewhere.)

After fixing your call I get this from the above calculation:

```
--request POST --data surveyId=MySurveyID&format=csv&useLabels=true --header "X-API-TOKEN: MyApiKey" --header "Content-Type: application/json"
```

Comment: Thanks for the catch! The server is still responding that it doesn't understand what I'm trying to do sadly though. Here is the message though:
`<HTML><HEAD>
<TITLE>Bad Request</TITLE>
</HEAD><BODY>
<H1>Bad Request</H1>
Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.<P>
Reference&#32;&#35;7&#46;44d3d93f&#46;1502907772&#46;0
</BODY>
</HTML>
`